# Create 1 million NSMutableArrays with unique names easily

Tags: iphone, for-loop, nsmutablearray

After teaching myself (mostly from this website) I have finally been unable to find a solution to a problem.
I am trying to easily create 1 million NSMutableArrays with unique names. What I mean by easily is not having 'hard code' all of the individual arrays.
What I would like to do is something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {  
    NSString *arrayNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];  
    NSString *millionArrayNumber = @"millionArrayNumber";  
    NSString *arrayName = [millionArrayNumber stringByAppendingString:arrayNumber];  
    NSMutableArray *[NSString arrayName] = [NSMutableArray array];  
}
```

I can understand why this doesn't work but I can't think of another way of doing it. I thought it might be possible to use something similar to:

```
[button setTag = 1];
```

If I change the code to:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {    
    NSMutableArray *millionArray = [NSMutableArray array];  
    [millionArray setTag: i];
}
```

I would then use the tag to control the arrays as you can do with buttons. This doesn't work for arrays though.
I hope I haven't been ambiguous.

Comment: How `NSMutableArray *[NSString arrayName] = [NSMutableArray array]; ` this code worked? doesnt it display error?

Comment: Yes it throws up an error. This is what I **wanted** to do though.

Comment: @user2573287 How about making an `NSMutableArray` and the adding the other 1000000 `NSMutableArrays` to it? That way you would have a "unique name" for each: its index in the array.

Comment: @user2573287 Also, get an idea about the C compilation process and why/how it is different from runtime. `NSMutableArray *[NSString arrayName]` is cute and naive, and is not supposed to work.

Comment: NSMutableArrays don't have names.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to convert a string into literal code like you're doing, but I think it's possible.

However, you can always just kick 1 million arrays to an NSMutableDictionary and give each one your unique key name.

```
NSMutableDictionary *arrayStore = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {  
    NSString *arrayNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];  
    NSString *millionArrayNumber = @"millionArrayNumber";  
    NSString *arrayName = [millionArrayNumber stringByAppendingString:arrayNumber];  
    arrayStore[arrayName] = [NSMutableArray array];  
}
```

And obviously to get whatever array you want later, you just use:

```
NSMutableArray *uniqueArray = arrayStore[arrayName];
```

Edit: Not sure if you want to keep the number as the unique key as mentioned in the comment below but if so, you can do it with this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *arrayStore = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) { 
   arrayStore[@(i)] = [NSMutableArray array];  
}
```

And access it with (for example, array number 100):

```
NSMutableArray *uniqueArray = arrayStore[@100];
```

Comment: Likewise, you could have an NSMutableArray store all those other arrays, and convert the string to a number, and number to string to access it.  Of course, there are other considerations, like memory.  Ever thought of using other persistant storage, like a database? SQLite comes for free with iOS.

Comment: 'Array'ception. I like it. I think it will work too. Thank you both for your input.

Comment: @Travis I was just about to say setObject:forKey: explicitly takes an NSString as a key but looked it up first and realised it takes an id that has to conform to NSCopying protocol, therefore has to be an 'object'. NSNumber therefore fits as a key. Just learnt something new :)  +1